# Listen for a specific IP address? (Python 3.x)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm searching for a method to get a simple python server to listen for a specific local IP address on my LAN using the socket import (assuming the destination computer has a client script).  `socket.bind()` and  `socket.listen(int)` methods cannot provide me with any options for filtering IP addresses. Am I missing a method?

Comment: Can't you just once you get a connection inspect the IP address and if it is not the desired one, immediately drop it?

Comment: `while True: if CurrentIPAddress != SpecIPAddress: #drop connection`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Python has a built-in method to do that.

However, as WhatsThePoint suggested, you can add your own filtering, as [`socket.recvfrom()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvfrom) will give you the client address, compare it with your required address, and if it's wrong, throw away the data.